# How to know whether I'm an admin hitting a console page?

Tags: wordpress, admin

To check whether a logged in user is using the site Wordpress offers the is_admin() function, but I can't figure out how I can check whether the page currently requested is a console page or a site page.

Any hints here?

Thanks
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

`is_admin()` checks if the currently viewed page is an admin page. `current_user_can( 'manage_options' )` will check if the currently logged-in user has admin capabilities.

Comment: Well, that's not what I need. I was after to find out whether the current logged in user is looking at a page like http://test.me/wp-admin/edit.php rather that a page with the content as any normal user would do.

Comment: are you sure `is_admin()` isn't what you need? see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin

Comment: well, as far as I saw it is not because once logged in and browing a front-end page the admin bar shown on top makes the is_admin returning true. That said, the description is pretty clear and it should work. Perhaps I did a mistake?